# Remote Desktop Software from Linux to Windows

Tags: windows, linux, remote-access

What software can I use to reach Windows from Linux via Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP)?

Windows supports remote desktop protocol in almost all versions, and the `mstsc` command exists in all modern versions of Windows. What are similar commands in Linux?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using rdesktop in command line.

For ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install rdesktop
```

You can also use different GUI clients for it like

- [tsclient](http://sourceforge.net/projects/remmina/)

  `sudo apt-get install tsclient`
- [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/)

  `sudo apt-get install tsclient`

and others.

BUT I prefer command line. 
I use alias file (rdp_aliases.bash) similar to following.

```
export RDP_SCREEN_WIDTH_HEIGHT="1280x800"
export RDP_WORKING_DIRECTORY=$HOME/RemoteDesktop
export RDP_DOMAIN=DOMAIN_NAME
export RDP_DEFAULT_USERNAME=ati.ozgur
export RDP_KEYBOARD=tr
export RDP_DEFAULTS="-r disk:atiD=/home/atillla/Downloads -r disk:atiP=/home/atillla/Projects"
export RDP_COMMAND="rdesktop $RDP_DEFAULTS -k $RDP_KEYBOARD -g $RDP_SCREEN_WIDTH_HEIGHT -c $RDP_WORKING_DIRECTORY"
export RDP_COMMAND_DOMAIN="rdesktop $RDP_DEFAULTS -k $RDP_KEYBOARD -g $RDP_SCREEN_WIDTH_HEIGHT -c $RDP_WORKING_DIRECTORY -d $RDP_DOMAIN -u $RDP_DEFAULT_USERNAME "
export RDP_COMMAND_NODOMAIN="rdesktop $RDP_DEFAULTS -k $RDP_KEYBOARD -g $RDP_SCREEN_WIDTH_HEIGHT -c $RDP_WORKING_DIRECTORY -u $RDP_DEFAULT_USERNAME "



alias rdpExample1="$RDP_COMMAND_NODOMAIN -T Title1 172.16.1.21 &"
alias rdpExampleDomain1="$RDP_COMMAND_NODOMAIN -T Title1 172.16.2.21 &"
alias rdpExampleDomain2="$RDP_COMMAND_DOMAIN -T Title1 172.16.2.21 &"
```

This puts everything in the same place, easier to manage and change. I also version control this file but it is another thing entirely.

Comment: Beware that [RDP is insecure](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54173/why-does-the-linux-xrdp-module-use-a-512-bit-rsa-key) and, except if used within a secure local network, should be wrapped in a secure tunnel (VPN, SSL, SSH).

Comment: AS of Nov 25, 2019, ["rdesktop is in need of a new maintainter."](http://www.rdesktop.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You may also install [Remmina](https://www.remmina.org/wp/) as the GUI:

> sudo apt-get install remmina